# GCCalendar overlapping

Tags: ios, calendar

I am using GCCalendar code to show day calendar view. I am facing a problem to handle overlapping events. Has anyone used GCCalendar and implemented solution for addressing the overlapping events issue?

Comment: The issue is been resolved, thanks for viewing

Comment: @SaqibSaud yes according to my requirement I did the resolution what is your exact requirement

Comment: I also had to add overlapping events, but fortunately.. i've found a GCCalendar fork, which works exactly as I require

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved by combining events occuring in same time slot into single event and adding description to event appropriately according to the requierment of the app.